# How to get private property of a mock trait via reflection?

Tags: php, reflection, phpunit, traits

Trait looks something like this:

```
trait A{

    private $model;

    public function __construct($model){
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->methodToStub();    
    }
...
}
```

When I try to get $model property of a mocked trait with a reflection in unit test:

```
$mock = $this->getMockForTrait(A::class,[],'MockedTrait', false, true, true, ['methodToStub']);
$mock->expects($this->exactly(1))->method('methodToStub');
$mock->__construct('model');

$reflection = new \ReflectionClass(A::class);
$property = $reflection->getProperty('model');
$property->setAccessible(true);
$value = $property->getValue($mock);
```

I receive this error:

> Undefined property: MockedTrait::$model

Any ideas, why?

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: It's a private variable, if you need to use it outside of the scope, make it public.

Comment: because `MockedTrait` class (and instance of it) really does not contain it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see is that you try to access the value of the MockedTrait::$model using the reflection of the A trait. But probably the "signature" of MockedTrait::$model is different from the one of A::$model.

Since Mock objects class are declared using eval in phpunit, MockedTrait class is reachable and you can try something like below:

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass(MockedTrait::class);
```

and this should work (probably).